# Wanna understant About Linking Pages

Tags: html, hyperlink

I´m still a learner.

I´m having a problem on linking my pages.

My initial page is:

[leatherjacksofficial.com](http://leatherjacksofficial.com)

without slash, neither "name.html" after the slash.

The site opens fine, but when I try to click the another links at first, in example "SHOWS".... it gets me this way: `https://leatherjacksofficial.com/#Shows`.

it´s strange because my menu code for the index.html file is like that:

```
 <div id="Menu_LIST">


<ul>

 <li><a href="https://leatherjacksofficial.com/index.html" target="_parent">HOME</a></li>

 <li><a href="https://leatherjacksofficial.com/shows.html" target="_parent">SHOWS</a></li>

 <li><a href="https://leatherjacks.bigcartel.com/" target="_parent">STORE</a></li>

 <li><a href="#PressKit" target="_parent">PRESS KIT</a></li>

 <li><a href="#Contact" target="_parent">CONTACT</a></li>

</ul>
```

the links that still haves de # tag, are just for me to guide myself.

Anyway... The other menu links never work.... Only if I click the HOME button. It takes me to `https://leatherjacksofficial.com/index.html`

THEN it works.... Why this happens?

Could someone help me please?

PS: I also noticed that lots of sites that only haves the `"name.com"` on it... Their sublinks never show the `.html` for it´s extensions...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you review the question content? Actually what you want and what you have given looks insufficient. You said you click on `SHOWS` it takes you to `https://leatherjacksofficial.com/#Shows` but in the menu code below you have given absolute link `https://leatherjacks.bigcartel.com`

Comment: Hi Kamal... One of the links don´t belong to my site... it´s an external one... All the links from my site are having this Hashtag problem

Comment: So the problem you are facing is with `#marker` navigation?

Comment: yes! example: I open the website. it´s: "https://leatherjacksofficial.com"

then I click on SHOWS... it makes "https://leatherjacksofficial.com/#Shows"

but if I make all open all my site again "https://leatherjacksofficial.com" and then click HOME instead of SHOWS... then it opens "https://leatherjacksofficial.com/index.html" and then I can open "shows.html" if I want to click SHOWS.. Am I putting my other html files wrongly? I´m putting all the html files at "public_html" folder...

Comment: The `#marker` is used to navigate inside a page to the element which has `id=marker` . Suppose you have a page `index.html` and one of the element inside this page has `id=shows` eg. `<div id='shows'>Some content</div>`. Suppose you have an anchor element like `<a href='/index.html#shows'>Shows</a>`. It will take you to the `index.html` first than, will search for element with `id=shows`, if found page will automatically get scrolled to bring that element into view. If not found the page will show as usual.

Comment: yeah... but I don´t have these elements... that´s what´s most strange =(

Comment: You can put this with any element. You just need to give id to the element and use #marker to that id.

Comment: Yeaaaah thank you Kamal! Now its working! I have another question.... My burger menu icon is Locked... Cant click... How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the worked solution from comment as answer with additional details to support answer.

The `#marker` is used to navigate inside a page to the element which has `id='marker'`. Suppose you have a page `index.html` and one of the element inside this page has `id='shows'` eg. `<div id='shows'>Some content</div>`. Suppose you have an anchor element like `<a href='/index.html#shows'>Shows</a>`. It will take you to the `index.html` first; than, will search for element with `id='shows'`, if found; page will automatically get scrolled to bring that element into view. If not found the page will show as usual.

*Note: You can put marker with any element. You just need to give `id` to the element and use `#marker` to that id.*

The key points to note are:

1. When the item with `#marker` is in a page, which do not have enough content to make page scroll, than the element should be already visible in view port, in that case clicking on the `#marker` (In page navigation links), will not make any UI scrolls and the page will look same, with or without clicking the link.
2. When the item with `#marker` is deep below the page, navigating to it will make the scroll only up to the point so that it comes to the view. Because content below is not sufficient to bring the `#marker` element to the top of window.

For your second query, the hamburger menu is not working, I can see that the linked web page `http://leatherjacksofficial.com` has already working hamburger. If there is any case where you face such problem, add the comment to this answer; I will help on that.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Amazing, Kamal!!! Wow thank you so much!! Im working hard here, but its working few by few hahHh!

Comment: @MauCor_LeatherJacks if the solution works for you, you can upvote by accepting the answer. Thanks!!